# Error in optimize in R for generating distribution parameters for a log-likelihood function

Tags: r, optimization, log-likelihood

I am trying to calculate distribution parameters to calculate log-likelihood values. Whilst "optim" seems to work for the function defined below, it obviously changes the output every time I change the starting value. I am trying to use "optimize" instead but I keep getting this error message

```
Error in if (par[1] < 0 | par[2] < 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am not sure how to move forward with this and all possible ways of fixing this error on the internet do not seem to be working. Please help, thank you in advance!

```
optim_cBeta <- function(par) 
{
   


  if ( par[1]< 0 | par[2] < 0)                 

  {
    output_cBeta = -Inf


  } else {

    
    output_cBeta = ( qbeta(0.025,par[1],par[2]) - 0.06)^2 +

                   ( qbeta(0.5,par[1],par[2]) - 0.07 )^2

                   + ( qbeta(0.975,par[1],par[2]) - 0.08 )^2
  
  
  }  

  print(c(output_cBeta, par[1],par[2]))
   
  return(output_cBeta)
    
}
```

optimize(optim_cBeta, lower = c(0,120), upper = c(100,3000), maximum = FALSE)

I tried to define par[1] = a, par[2] = b inside the function, and replaced those in the objective function "output_cBeta", but keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html: you need `x0` in the call to optimize.

Comment: do you mean add optimize(x0 = optim_cBeta, lower = c(0,120), upper = c(100,3000), maximum = FALSE)?

Comment: No. The first argument is the function. The second argument is `x0`: the initial values (this also determines the size of the problem). Obviously, you can't mix these two. You may want to reread the documentation and some of the examples.